# Need to open link in safari from uiwebview?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have stored my whole html document with escape sequence in a variable... 
and it contains some anchor tag.. where if that has clicked, it should open in safari, not in my app webview....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following code for that.

```
   -(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
        if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
            return NO;
        }

        return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this..... it works when i pass url in uiwebview.... now its not working... anything else????

Comment: You can also use the directly insert the url name.

Comment: Yeah.... but my requirement is to change that url to string which contains my whole document.... and i accomplished that. now i need to open the link in uiwebview in safari, i have used the above methods but i couldn't get succeed..

Comment: i implement this thinks into my demo app it's work fine if you want to get the those code pls give me your mail id if possible

Answer (score 3):

You can use the UIWebViewDelegate protocol to achieve this:

```
// assuming webView is a valid UIWebView
webView.delegate = self;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)wv shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)rq navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)nt
{
    if (nt == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkCkicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[rq URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code: UIWebViewNavigationTypeLink**Ckicked** should be UIWebViewNavigationTypeLink**Clicked**